# What is the best way to do work on SMS_RECEIVED on Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a working application that uses a BroadcastReceiver to process incoming SMS messages. My question is what is the best way to do work on an incoming SMS? Currently I am launching a new thread to do the work, as shown below in the onReceive() method of my BroadcastReceiver.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(ANDROID_SMS_DELIVER)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            try{
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    final String smsFrom = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    final String smsBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                    // Launch a thread to do work on the SMS
                    new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            // Work..
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the best way? Alternatively, should I be sending a broadcast to some other IntentService to do the work, or will this work just as well?

Thanks.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver will only be alive for x seconds (I thought 10), I don't know what will happen with the Thread. You could easily try it out if it works. But if it was my call I would use a IntentService: more clear and defined behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the way to do it! The `BroadcastReceiver` will only be alive for 10 seconds (give or take). I have no clue what will happen with your thread.

The best way to do is use a `IntentService`. This `Service` is launched/started via an `Intent` and will shutdown itself when done.

Comment: Would the `goAsync` call make my implementation viable?

Comment: According to the docs yes, I think this is also usable. This is available from API 11 (Android 3.0)